# bash script array

Tags: bash

```
array=('org.battery.plist' 'org.disk.plist' 'org.memory.plist');

echo "1) org.battery.plist"
echo "2) org.disk.plist"
echo "3) org.memory.plist"

echo "Enter selection(s) to load, separated by commas: "
read var

sudo launchctl load -w ${array[$var]}
```

Am I on the right track? I'm a little stuck. Can someone help?

If user inputs 1, 2, I expect the script to perform this below -

```
sudo launchctl load -w org.disk.plist
sudo launchctl load -w org.memory.plist
```

Comment: try `select ... in ...` statement in `bash`. type `help select` in the terminal for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
IFS=","
for i in $var
do
    sudo launchctl load -w ${array[$i - 1]}
done
```

You will also need to check whether the input is out of array bounds and throw and error.

Answer (score 1):

There is a buildin in bash for such selects, surprisingly, called 'select':

```
select entry in ${array[@]}; 
do  
    sudo launchctl load -w $entry
done
```

Try `help select`.

Comment: `help select` should work, as it's a shell built-in.  `man select` will probably give you the manpage for the (unrelated) syscall.

Answer (score 0):

This is better:

```
array=('org.battery.plist' 'org.disk.plist' 'org.memory.plist');

for (( i=0;i<"${#array[@]}";i++ )) ; do
    let n=i+1
    printf '%d) %s\n' $n "${array[$i]}"
done

IFS=, read -r -p 'Enter selection(s) to load, separated by commas: ' -a selections

for selection in "${selections[@]}" ; do
    let selection=selection-1
    sudo launchctl load -w "${array[$selection]}"
done
```